# SharePoint 2013: Sync Active Directory Detail Information with SharePoint Users

Tags: profile-sync, ad

I am setting up a new SharePoint 2013 environment and the customer is requesting that the detailed information from Active Directory (phone #, email, fax, etc.) be synced with the user information in SharePoint. He wants it so that when an employee clicks on a users profile, they can see the information that has been pulled from Active Directory. I have set up SharePoint a few times now and I have never had this request. Any guidance or advice is welcomed! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's how it works already. No action needed.

Answer (score 0):

Once User Profile Sync is setup then most of the mappings will be there, see
http://www.harbar.net/archive/2013/02/18/Default-Active-Directory-Import-User-Profile-Property-Mappings-in-SharePoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Active Directory Import feature in SharePoint 2013. Almost attributes can be synced to SharePoint user profiles.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx